# Yandex maps WMS server

Tags: wms, tile-map-service, yandex

I want to add **Yandex** satellite imagery map as layer by using **WMS** server. But I cannot find one. The only link I could find is **TMS** server (which is working fine): https://sat01.maps.yandex.net/tiles?l=sat&v=3.379.0&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}

My questions are:

1. Is there any **WMS** servers with **Yandex** maps?
2. Is there any workaround to use **TMS server as WMS**?

Comment: By so far I can refer you to using a plugin QuickMapServices, where you may find Yandex Map, Yandex Narod Map, and Yandex Satellite.

Comment: Thank you, Taras! I know that I can use TMS server through QuickMapServices in QGIS. But I'm working with another software (whic is not GIS), where default functionality allows to use different GIS maps by setting up WMS server only.

Comment: `Is there any workaround to use TMS server as WMS?` Possibly MapProxy ~ https://github.com/mapproxy/mapproxy, but I've never tried it...

Comment: Hi, it is OT comment but I hope you could know this if you plan to implement Yandex satellite imagery map as layer in your software - do you know which rules apply to Yandex imagery use? For Bing Aerial I know how to cite it and for which purposes I am allowed to use it. Cannot find that for Yandex (and Yandex satellite has much better imagery not only for Europe - compared to Bing). thanks